# Numba: sharing a numpy array among processes

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, numba

I have a numpy array X. I want to share it among processes. In each process I call a function foo(), which reads X. I want foo() to be jitted, eg.:

```
    X = np.zeros(1000)

    @jit(nopython=True)
    def foo(i):
        return np.max(X[:,i])

    pool = mp.Pool(processes=10)
    for i in range(10):
        pool.apply_async(foo, args=(i,))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

My issue is sharing X among the processes.

1. Numba doesn't like global variables.
2. If I put everything into a class, Numba gives me an error 
   `"cannot determine Numba type of <class '__main__.MyClass'>"`

How can I share X among all the processes without each process having to read it in and/or pickling X?

Comment: I haven't worked with numba before- I just tried running your code above, as-is, and did not hit any errors. Can you elaborate a little bit on what your concern is here?

Comment: Doesn't numba automatically parallelize everything for you (with `@jit(..., parallel=True)`? Why do you explicitly want to use `Pool`?